# How to use JSON to retrieve dbpedia json data

Tags: javascript, json

In my php code, I am retrieving json data as below.

```
<?php
$url = "http://dbpedia.org/data/Los_Angeles.json";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
echo $data;
?>
```

The javascript code consumes this json data returned from php and gets the json object as below.

```
var doc = eval('(' + request.responseText + ')');
```

How to retrieve the following json data using dot notations where the keys contain URLs. 
My guess is to use encoding. Please guide along these lines

```
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/populationTotal" : [
{ "type" : "literal",
  "value" : 3792621 ,
  "datatype" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" } ] ,
"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace/areaTotal" : [
{ "type" : "literal",
  "value" : "1301.9688931491348" ,
  "datatype" : "http://dbpedia.org/datatype/squareKilometre" }
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval` and not `JSON.parse()`? What have you tried? Note that [the example JSON above **is not a valid JSON text.**](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation". Filing "JSON object notation" to the department of redundancy department.

Comment: It looks like they are using PHP to fetch the JSON and JavaScript to parse it. Still `eval()` is redundant